# Do something when app closed in android

Tags: android, action, oncloselistener

when user exit the android app in the normal way (No Hard Exit like Force Close) i want the app to do something

im working on some kind of chat app and i want the app to update user status make it offline when the user close the app.

i try few solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: What is "the normal way"? BACK? HOME? Accepting an incoming phone call? Responding to a `Notification` in the status bar? Switching to another app from the recent-tasks list? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes this is the normal way and there is the hard way which if Force Close from Settings>apps

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement a `Service` and then bind your `Activity` to the service so that it is aware of the Activity's state.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html